# For Loop to While Loop using IN for while loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I am quite new to Python 2.7 so I had a couple of questions regarding using for loops to while loops.

For example: I am writing this definition

```
def missingDoor(trapdoor,roomwidth,roomheight,step):        
    safezone = []
    hazardflr = givenSteps(roomwidth,step,True)
    safetiles = []

    for m in hazardflr:
        safetiles.append((m,step))
        i = 0
        while i < len(safetiles):
            nextSafe = safetiles[i]
            if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, nextSafe[0], nextSafe[1]):
                if trapdoor[nextSafe[0]/roomwidth][nextSafe[0]%roomwidth] is "0":
                    if nextSafe[0] not in safezone:
                        safezone.append(nextSafe[0])
                    for e in givenSteps(roomwidth,nextSafe[0],True):
                        if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, e, nextSafe[0]):
                            if trapdoor[e/roomwidth][e%roomwidth] is "0" and (e,nextSafe[0]) not in safetiles:
                                safetiles.append((e,nextSafe[0]))
            i += 1  
    return sorted(safezone)
```

I am trying to turn all the for loops to a while loops, so this is currently what I have written so far. I actually dont know if we say "While e in " works near the middle of the code. But using the while loop rules, will this code do the same as the for loop one?

```
safezone = []
hazardflr = givenSteps(roomwidth,step,True)
safetiles = []
m=0
while m < hazardflr:
    safetiles.append((m,step))
    i = 0
    while i < len(safetiles):
        nextSafe = safetiles[i]
        if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, nextSafe[0], nextSafe[1]):
            if trapdoor[nextSafe[0]/roomwidth][nextSafe[0]%roomwidth] is "0":
                if nextSafe[0] not in safezone:
                    safezone.append(nextSafe[0])
                    e=0
                while e in givenSteps(roomwidth,nextSafe[0],True):
                    if knownSafe(roomwidth, roomheight, e, nextSafe[0]):
                        if trapdoor[e/roomwidth][e%roomwidth] is "0" and (e,nextSafe[0]) not in safetiles:
                            safetiles.append((e,nextSafe[0]))
                    e+=1        
        i += 1
    m+=1
return sorted(safezone)
```

thanks for any advice or help!

Comment: "I am trying to turn all the for loops to a while loops" — Why?

Comment: @MattDMo: Actually, it is; `in` there is just the membership test operator.

Comment: @MattDMo What is wrong on `while e in ...`?

Comment: @SteveZrg Usually in Python, coders shall learn the opposite direction, turning not effective `while` loops accessing items by index to use of `for` loop. But there could be reasons like here, when the iterable is modified during processing (see `safetiles.append((e, nextSafe[0]))` Anyway, you shall do `while` loops only if you have good reason for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
while aList:
     m= hazardflr.pop()
    # ...
```

should be roughly equivelent to your other loop

Comment: Except this has the side effect of destroying the original list, which may not be wanted.

Answer (score 1):

### No, your code isn't identical.

While they look similar, `for item in list` and `while item in list` will do **wildly different things**.

- `for item  in list` is a syntactic way of saying for every item in the list - do something with is.
- `while item in list` is different - a `while` loop iterates as long as the condition is true. The condition in this case being `item in list`. It doesn't update the item each iteration and if you never change what `item` or `list` are, it might never terminate. Additionally, if any given item isn't in the list it may terminate prematurely.

**If you want to iterate through a list and keep a count, using `while` is the wrong way to go about it. Use the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function instead.**

`enumerate()` takes a list, and returns a list of tuples, with each item from the list in order with its index, like so:

```
for i,m in enumerate(hazardflr):
    safetiles.append((m,step))
```

This small change means you no longer have to track your indices manually.

If you are iterating through *every* item in a list in Python - **use `for`** that's what it is designed to do.

Comment: So, how do i rewrite this code using enumerate? Do I just replace the while loop with for i,m in enumerate(hazardflr):

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what `givenSteps` returns, but in general, no.  `for x in foo` evaluates `foo` once and then assigns `x` to be each element of `foo` in turn.  `while x in foo: ... x += 1`, on the other hand, evaluates `foo` on every iteration and will end early if `foo` is not a contiguous sequence.  For example, if `foo = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6]`, `for` will use every value of `foo`, but `while` will end after 2, because 3 is not in `foo`.  `while` will also differ from `for` if `foo` contains any non-integral values or values below the starting value.